# Parse letter or number with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to write a parser for strings such as `x`, `A` (i.e. single letters), `657` and `0` (i.e. integer positive numbers).
Here is the code I wrote.

```
import Text.Parsec

data Expression = String String | Number Int

value = letter <|> many1 digit
```

However I get the following error.

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
```

- How to convert `Char -> String` inside the parser?
- What should the type annotation be for `value` ?

Comment: What is this `Expression` for?

Comment: I believe that the goal of parsing is to have a semantic representation of the data so we need a data type

Comment: @Blincer (off topic, was in the middle answering and your question got deleted. FWIW https://editor.p5js.org/george.profenza/sketches/3nLBvI_vA). TLDR; Canvas is limited,  it will antialias, but you can redraw stuff at a larger size. (Can probably do the same with raw pixels / Canvas ImageData, but you get a bit of flexibility with p5.Graphics (e.g. ellipse pixels, etc.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter` parses just a single letter and returns a `Char`. You want to parse a `String`, namely `[Char]` (it's the same thing), so I guess you want to parse `many letter`?

But if you want to parse just a single letter as a `String` you can take advantage of the fact that `Parsec _ _` has a `Functor` instance in order to map over its result and pack it in a list:

```
value :: Parsec s u String 
value = fmap (:[]) letter <|> many1 digit
```

---

After the edit I guess you want to parse the `Expression` you have presented to us, so you will need some more fancy fmapping to wrap the results in proper constructors:

```
value :: Parsec s u Expression 
value = fmap (String . (:[])) letter
    <|> fmap (Number . read) (many1 digit)
```

Comment: I am trying to parse single letters

Comment: Covered this case

Comment: `(String . pure)` would be cleaner.

Comment: Also, parsers are cheap :) `value = string <|> number where string = (String.pure) <$> letter; number = read <$> many1 digit`.

Comment: I don't like `pure` here as it mixes in my eyes with the Applicative instance of the parser